# Clip stops at frame 100

Tags: edit-mode, timeline, movie-clip-editor

I added a clip (19s) by drag and drop in Blender (Layout). When I press the play button, the clip works normally...till frame 100, then the picture stopped but in the timeline it moves forward.
Frame start is 300 and Frame end is 1600.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Check your keyframes. You added one by accident.

Comment: provide your blend file

Comment: I added the clip in a new general file and got the same problem. It stopped at frame 100. So there is no error in my file. The clip is MPEG-4 with 250 MB - 19s (1920x1080)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Problem was the object data properties frames. It was 100. Thanks guys.